# Jasmine: Mocking ViewChild component, Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have `Parent Component` which has `View child` component associated with it. I'm trying to set up unit test for `parent component` but i'm not able to override the `View Child` component with mock class. I tried `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`, `CUSTOM_SCHEMA` in Schema provider and also used `ng2-mock-component`.

```js
describe('Mobile Application Card:', () => {
  let comp: MobileAppCardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MobileAppCardComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const mock = MockComponent({ selector: 'bt-modal'}); // View Child Component. 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MobileAppCardComponent, mock],
      providers: [{provide: MobileAppService, useValue: serviceStub},
                  {provide: ToastService, useValue: {}},
                  {provide: Router, userValue: null }
                 ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MobileAppCardComponent);
  });
});
```